# iptables block almost everything on one interface and allow certain on other interface

Tags: iptables

I have a vps and its interface is `venet0:0`.

I would like to block all incoming traffic from that interface and allow only on certain ports:

- tcp 22223-29
- udp 33330
- tcp 33332

Also I want to allow all established connections which orginate from the server to the internet.

There is also a second virtual interface called `tun1` and I want to block everything on that interface except the ports:

- tcp 44430
- udp 44431

I am lost on how to block everything at this point.

Here is an example of what I already have, but apache still works on the public IP, while it should not.

```
# Flushing all rules iptables --flush iptables --delete-chain iptables -F iptables -X


### interface section use public Internet (venet0:0) ### iptables -A INPUT -i venet0:0 -j DROP

# Setting default filter policy iptables -P INPUT DROP iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT iptables -P FORWARD DROP

#################################################
# allow loopback
#################################################

iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

#################################################
# drop all ICMP
#################################################

iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type any -j DROP iptables -A OUTPUT
-p icmp -j DROP

#################################################
# allow established connections
#################################################

iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

#################################################
# allow public per port
#################################################

# 22223 iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22223 -j ACCEPT


# 1194 OpenVPN iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Is this the exact order?  RELATED,ESTABLISHED should be rule #1.  iptables -A INPUT -j DROP should be the last rule.  The accept rules go in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Anything including icmp which is not explicitly allowed is dropped.

```
#allow related,established
iptables -A INPUT  -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
#Don't mess with loopback
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
#accept 2 port for tun1
iptables -A INPUT -i tun1 -p tcp --dport 44430 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i tun1 -p udp --dport 44431 -j ACCEPT
#accept venet0:0 stuff
iptables -A INPUT -i venet0:0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22223:22229,33332 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i venet0:0 -p udp --dport 33330  -j ACCEPT
#literally drop everything else on every adapter
#then default policy doesn't matter
#seen default policy fail to block, maybe it required a reboot
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

FORWARD

```
#allow related,established
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
#Don't mess with loopback
iptables -A FORWARD -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i venet0:0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22223:22229,33332 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i venet0:0 -p udp --dport 33330  -j ACCEPT
#accept 2 port for tun1
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun1 -p tcp --dport 44430 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun1 -p udp --dport 44431 -j ACCEPT

#Add before DROP rule
#If venet0:0 and tun1 are supposed to talk to each other
#Add next 2 lines (or leave them out and they can't)
iptables -A FORWARD -i venet0:0 -o tun1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun1 -o venet0:0  -j ACCEPT

#anything not allowed anywhere dropped.
iptables -A FORWARD -j DROP
```